# Recaptcha V2 with Formtoemailpro

Tags: recaptcha

Has anyone edited `formtoemailpro` to use Recaptcha v2? This is the `formtoemailpro` developer version which gives you a PHP script: (https://formtoemail.com/developer_pricing.php)

I tried changing

```
// Check reCAPTCHA
if($reCAPTCHA)
{
    require_once('recaptchalib.php');
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer($privatekey,$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],$_REQUEST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],$_REQUEST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
    if(!$resp->is_valid)
    {
        $errors[] = "The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again (reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")";
    }
    unset($_REQUEST["recaptcha_challenge_field"]);
    unset($_REQUEST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
}
```

to

```
// Check reCAPTCHA
if($reCAPTCHA)
{
    //require_once('recaptchalib.php');
    //$resp = recaptcha_check_answer($privatekey,$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],$_REQUEST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],$_REQUEST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer($privatekey,$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],$_REQUEST["g-recaptcha-response"]);
    if(!$resp->is_valid)
    {
        $errors[] = "The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again (reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")";
    }
    unset($_REQUEST["g-recaptcha-response"]);
}
```

But got errors.

```
This page isn’t working
webeg.uk is currently unable to handle this request.
```

Test is at http://webeg.uk/aaq/

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution, please feel free to test and critique:

In place of the existing reCaptcha lines in formtoemailpro as above, enter the following:

```
// Check reCAPTCHA
if($reCAPTCHA)
{   
if(isset($_REQUEST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
      $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    }
    if(!$captcha){
      echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form.</h2>';
      exit;
    }
    $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$privatekey&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    if($response.success==true)            
    {
    unset($_REQUEST['g-recaptcha-response']);
    }

  }
```

Thank you